# Ubuntu install freezes after "Install Ubuntu" from the grub menu

Tags: system-installation, dell, 22.04, freeze

I am trying to install ubuntu 22.04 in a Dell all in one Inspiron 24 5410.

When I boot from my USB, I choose "Try or Install Ubuntu" from the grub menu and it freezes with a black screen. The video card is Intel (R) UHD Graphics and the grub is version 2.06

I already tried

1. To make the USB iso with rufus instead of the ubuntu
2. Do disable security boot and safe mode in the bios
3. Change the HD (SSD) option to Raid on
4. Edit de grub with the option nomodeset or i915.modeset=0
5. To use the 20.04 version
6. Save Graphics option

As some asked I already update the bios and everything using the Dell app in windows

The question below mentions many possible reasons. I already tried with other USB and checked the ISO is not corrupted. I think the hardware (Inspirion 24 5410) is compatible with ubuntu. Most of the other reasons mentioned are too technical and I have no idea to know if there are the reason. Is there a way for me to get any new information about the possible reason of my problem?

[Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Does anyone has any suggestion? I have basic knowledge of linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: #1 is pointless; #2 Do you mean "Secure Boot" and "Fast Boot"? If so, yes, there's no harm in disabling both although neither should impact installation and usage; #3 is just dumb, use AHCI only; #4 shouldn't be needed at all; #5 waste of time.

Comment: Here's what you SHOULD do: 1. Update UEFI and any SSD's firmware if applicable; 2. Try Ubuntu (with safe graphics) after making sure the ISO you're using ISN'T corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Just let the USB stick boot up into a live environment. From there choose install Ubuntu ( ( an icon on the desktop ) after checking that all your hardware works ). If you are sure that all your hardware already works, you can choose 'install Ubuntu' earlier in the bootprocess of the USB device. 
I have never seen an option 'install Ubuntu' in a grub menu btw.

Comment: There is an option to install instead of running a live session ("Try Ubuntu"). It was always there. And I'm afraid the problem is more complicated than just waiting for it to boot properly.

Comment: That could be, of course. Your suggestion to try it with safe graphics makes sense in that case. Didn't think of unsupported screens. The videocard is supported.

Comment: I already tried safe graphics and it does not work. I do not have the option to only try ubuntu. In the grub (v2.06) the option is "Try or Install Ubuntu"

Comment: @ThiagoRodriguesdeOliveira You need to start reading the comments, namely https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434720/ubuntu-install-freezes-after-install-ubuntu-from-the-grub-menu#comment2500361_1434720 and report back by editing the question.